# Movie about humanoid alien brother and sister stranded on Earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie as a kid. It is about two kids (brother and sister) who are from outer space but somehow stranded on earth and have lost contact to their parents.

I remember that they wanted to get to some kind of alien spaceship launch in time but barely missed it which was very sad. I think this was how the story ended so maybe there also was a part 2? Or was it a TV show?

I would guess it was from the 90's or 80's.

Comment: My impulse is one of the Witch Mountain movies, but they were picked up at the end.

Comment: TV show Roswell has brother and sister and a friend who are aliens.  Only watched a few episodes so not sure if it matches that storyline though.

Answer (score 13):

This reminds me of the movie *Escape from Witch Mountain*.  There is a pair of twins (boy and a girl), with special abilities who end up in an orphanage, discover they are actually aliens, and race to make a spaceship launch.  Misses include that I think they make the ship in the version I saw.

There are apparently three or four versions, from the novel in 1968, movies in 75, 95, and 2009, and a failed tv series in 82 - so one of them might have had the kids missing the ship as a plot twist... actually, the tv attempt might make the most sense, as that would give a starting point for the story to continue, instead of finish?
I hope you find it.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, although (in at least the book and 1975 film) the siblings don't miss their flight, so to say.  Also, the brother and sister weren't twins: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_to_Witch_Mountain_%281975_film%29

Comment: sorry, wrote that bit before I checked

Answer (score 0):

It's called  *Caravan of Courage, an Ewok Adventure*.It was made for TV movie from 1984, and I too thought I had fever-dreamed it into existence, but I just googled the hell out of it and just found it. :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I skimmed the plot and I think to many things don't really match. But I will watch it just to check. :)

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE, can you try and provide some plot points or links so that users don't have to go searching for the information, it'll make your answer look loads neater.